# iosChart not displaying LineChartView points in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, ios-charts

The following is based on the `LineChartView` example ([from youtube](https://youtu.be/vB6HqH-hMZ0)) which worked fine in a standard View (single view app) &  the `BarChartView` worked fine in a `TableViewCell` using the identical idiom to that shown below. I have a time expiring every two seconds to update the cells however not hooked-up yet.

The x,y Axis are generated correctly (final graphic showing just 2 of the 9 cells), it's just that the points are not plotted. However, failure only occurs in the `LineChartView`. I've viewed other references to this issue but not found my specific fix yet. Any ideas?

**The TableViewController**

```
class GraphTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let model = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var timer: Timer? = nil
    var noSamples = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lineChart_cell", for: indexPath)
        let graphCell = cell as? LineGraphCell

        graphCell!.setChartValues()
        print("\(model[indexPath.row])")
        return graphCell!
    }

    @objc func fireTimer() {
        print("Timer Fired")
        noSamples += 1
        (view as? UITableView)?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**The TableViewCell implementation is shown below:**

```
class LineGraphCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lineChart: LineChartView!

    let x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    let y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    func setChartValues() {

        var values = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for index in x {
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(y[index]))
            values.append(value)
        }

        let set1 = ChartDataSet(entries: values, label: "Set1")
        let data = ChartData(dataSet: set1)

        // Some debug output
        if data.entryCount > 0 {
            let yValue = "\(values[data.entryCount-1].y)"
            print("Y : \(yValue)")
            for value in values {
                print("\(value.y) ", terminator: "")
            }
        }
        self.lineChart.data = data
    }

}
```

**The storyboard is set up as follows:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: where is so setChartValues metthod?

Comment: its in cellForRowAt in the TableViewController class.

Comment: your ChartDataSet should be LineChartDataSet

Comment: Thanks for that fixed -  in addition ChartData needs to-be LineChartData

Comment: i already posted answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

try using following ...

```
let x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
func setChartValues() {

    var values = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for index in x {
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(y[index]))
        values.append(value)
    }

let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: values, label: "Set1")
set1.color = UIColor.blue // red // green whatever you want. 
let data = LineChartData()
data.addDataSet(data:set1)

    // Some debug output
    if data.entryCount > 0 {
        let yValue = "\(values[data.entryCount-1].y)"
        print("Y : \(yValue)")
        for value in values {
            print("\(value.y) ", terminator: "")
        }
    }
    self.lineChart.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your `ChartDataSet` with `LineChartDataSet` like below

**Old Code:**

```
let set1 = ChartDataSet(entries: values, label: "Set1")
let data = ChartData(dataSet: set1)
```

**Replace With:**

```
 let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: values, label: "Set1")
 let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
```

This will solve your problem.